# How to remove everything before pattern?

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to remove everything before a pattern, but when it has a "?" and whitespaces I think it doesn't work.

```
question <- "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements? - I am happy"
```

```
str_remove(question, "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements? - ")
[1] "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements? - I am happy"
```

If I do this I get this:

```
str_remove(question, "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements?")
[1] "? - I am happy"
```

In the end I'm looking to get only this:

```
[1] "I am happy"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may change the pattern to match characters (`.*`) followed by `?` (metacharacter - so escape `\\`), followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`) then a `-` and one of more spaces (`\\s+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(question, ".*\\?\\s+-\\s+")
[1] "I am happy"
```

---

In `base R`, use `trimws`

```
trimws(question, whitespace = ".*\\?\\s+-\\s+")
[1] "I am happy"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `?` is being interpreted as a regex quantifier (https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

You can use `fixed=TRUE` to interpret the pattern literally.

```
question <- "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements? - I am happy"

sub(pattern = "How much do you agree or disagree to the following statements? - ",
    replacement = "",
    x = question,
    fixed = TRUE)
[1] "I am happy"
```